# TX_BAD_AUTH, no idea why

Tags: horizon, javascript-sdk, stellar-sdk

i'm moving from testnet to pubnet but for some reason my code didn't work with pubnet.
here some snippet.
Of course sourceAccount,des.publicKey and sourceKeys contain what i'm expeting.

sourceAccount contain pubKey of sender
des.publicKey() contain pubkey of receiver
and sourceKeys is a keypair from Secret.
This works well on testnet but not on pubnet
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you copy the full code, as text?

Comment: is too long for stackexchange's comment space, but even if i set the 3 variables the line over the transaction's building it return me tx_bad_auth error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed adding `StellarSdk.Network.usePublicNetwork();` before signin the transaction.